# How to perform t-test in R between 2 categorical variables (Yes / No)

Tags: r

[image]

Hi, i have 2 categorical variables and i was told to perform t-test between these 2.

so i key in my R code as

```
> t.test(BPMeds ~ TenYearCHD, data=data_no_na)
```

And i am getting a error

> Error in var(x) : Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.   Use
> something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant
> vector. In addition: Warning message: In mean.default(x) : argument is
> not numeric or logical: returning NA

I was told to Print out my results for t, p-values and mean for this group

T_T

anyone can help?

Comment: For comparing categorical variables, shouldn't you use a Chi-squared test?

Comment: I think so too becos the question post to me was using T-test...and i am weak on the theory part so wasn't sure if categorical variables can use T-test or not.

Comment: What is a `t.test`? What is it used for? By answering these questions, you will be able to understand why you are getting an error

Comment: You cannot perforrm a t-test between 2 categorical variables. Probably you should look into your dataset. there may be a reason why you have been asked for a t.test. Probabbly you do have a numerical variable somewhere